# Simple Augmented Reality Application in Unity with Vuforia

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am trying to develop a simple AR application in Unity with Vuforia following a beginner tutorial but even I follow exactly the steps that are described when I run the application on my phone nothing appears. I have activated the parameters "**Load Database**" and "**activate**" but still it doesn't work. Do you know what's the problem? How can I place the Image Target in front of the ARCamera? I have uploaded some photos to make clear how my settings look like [Settings of the ARCamera1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bd73L.jpg) [Settings of the ARCamera2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8pr0.jpg). Any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You do have a printed copy of your image target in the real world, yes? You are pointing your phone camera at it, yes? Have you tried running the sample scene? Does it work?

Comment: Yes, I have the printed image in the real world and I am pointing the camera on it. It works perfectly on the webcam of my computer but not when I deploy it on my android phone. Is there any special setting I should do in order to deploy it on my android phone? Thank you.

Comment: The way you worded your question made me wonder. Good, you didn't do something *excessively* dumb. So it only doesn't work on the phone... Did you make sure to include the "access camera" permission request? Did you grant it when you installed the app?

Comment: Yes I did it. The camera opens and when I point it on the printed image nothing appears (a virtual object should appear every time the printed image is recognized).

Comment: Just going over the troubleshooting I can think of with the information I have available. I can't think of anything else though. Got me stumped for the time being.

Comment: The android version of my device is 6.0.1 . Yes I'm building with a USB cable. In the build settings the development mode is already unchecked. Thank you.